# input field in html javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a small issue: I want to out the input field in the HTML text (see picture):

[image: Snapshot]

Here is my code:

```html
   <div class="container content-center" id="margin">
        <form name="formcalc">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Einkommen</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <!-- <div class="input-group-addon">Fr.</div> -->
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtnum1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset disabled>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Number 1</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" value="Fr. " readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Number 2</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres2" value="Fr. " readonly>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Berechnen" onClick="sumValues()">
        </form>
        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <section class="container">
            <p class="lead" id="lead"> Number 1 is: XXX. Number 2 is: XXX.
            </p>

        </section>

    </div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Post some javascript/jquery code of things that you already tried

Comment: I did try but deleted the code. I thought maybe some of you guys can help me

Comment: You didn't add any dynamic value in xxx and you must call a click event and at click you must add the content with javascript or jquery

Comment: Get the values of inputs by Id giving an id attribute, then add them to the Dom with innerHtml or better appendChild. just remember to first parse the values because they are text.

Answer (score 1):

You must create the sumValues() function. In it you should do something like:

```
function sumValue() {
    document.getElementById('lead').innerText = "Number 1 is: " + document.getElementById('n1').value + " Number 2 is:" + document.getElementById('n2').value + "."
}
```

For this to work, you must add the attribute "id" (n1 and n2) to each input, like:

```
<input id="n1" type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres" value="Fr. " readonly>

<input id="n2" type="text" class="form-control" name="txtres2" value="Fr. " readonly>
```

It should work with that. Also, the name "sumValue()" doesn't do any sum, so it's misleading, unless it exists but you didn't posted it.

Comment: The question is tagged with JQuery, so you can use jquery selector instead of those large `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Can you guys show me what do you mean by a complete code section? I am new to this :/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If you already have javascript on your page, place it with that. Otherwise, place it in a script tag at the bottom of the`<body>` in your HTML:

```
<script>
  num1 = $('[name=txtres]').val();
  num2 = $('[name=txtres2]').val();

  $('#lead').text("Number 1 is: " + num1 + ". Number 2 is: " + num2 + ".");
</script>
```

Make sure to place it after the `<script>` that loads jQuery.

---

### jquery:

To get the values of the inputs:

```
num1 = $('[name=txtres]').val();
num2 = $('[name=txtres2]').val();
```

Then to change the text:

```
$('#lead').text("Number 1 is: " + num1 + ". Number 2 is: " + num2 + ".");
```

---

### Vanilla javascript:

To get the values of the inputs:

```
num1 = document.getElementsByName("txtres")[0];
num2 = document.getElementsByName("txtres2")[0];
```

Then to change the text:

```
document.getElementById("lead").textContent = "Number 1 is: " + num1 + ". Number 2 is: " + num2 + ".";
```

Comment: where to put this code? in the HTML code, container?

Comment: it worked! But why I need to press the bottom twice before the input values shows?

Comment: yes. I have it like this:
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function sumValues() {

           
            $('#lead').text("Number 1 is: " + num1 + ". Number 2 is: " + num2 + ".");
           
    
        }

        
    </script>

Comment: @zenubeh could you edit your question to clarify what your asking? From the picture it looks like you just want to get the two numbers, but from your function named sumValues(), it looks like you are trying to do more. Any additional info would be very helpful :)

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow can sho show me how to put code ein here

Comment: Sure. Click on the 'edit' button under your question. This will bring up the editor. Next, you can write code by using three Grave accents (this thing => `) like so: \```Code goes here\``` make sure to end your code with three more Grave accents

Comment: ```<script type="text/javascript">
        function sumValues() {
            var num1;
            var num3;
            var num4;
            num1 = Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
            num3 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) / 12;
            num4 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) * 15500;```

Comment: ```num5 = $('[name=txtres]').val();
            num6 = $('[name=txtres2]').val();
            $('#lead').text("Number 1 is: " + num5 + ". Number 2 is: " + num6 + ".");
           
            document.formcalc.txtres.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num3) + '.-';
            document.formcalc.txtres2.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num4) + '.-';
        }        
    </script>```

Comment: OK, got it. Is it working now? If it is not working, what is wrong with it?

Comment: When I type the button for the first time the text appears but without the input values. When I press the button for the second time than the input values appears. So I need to press the button twice

Comment: Have you removed the place holder text from the HTML? Current: ```<p class="lead" id="lead"> Number 1 is: XXX. Number 2 is: XXX.</p>```. New: ```<p class="lead" id="lead"></p>```

Comment: Hmm, my last guess would be ```<script type="text/javascript">
  function sumValues() {
    var num1 = Number(document.formcalc.txtnum1.value);
    var num3 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) / 12;
    var num4 = ((num1 * 0.12) - (num1 * 0.118)) * 15500;
    var num5 = $('[name=txtres]').val();
    var num6 = $('[name=txtres2]').val();
    $('#lead').text("Number 1 is: " + num5 + ". Number 2 is: " + num6 + ".");
    document.formcalc.txtres.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num3) + '.-';
    document.formcalc.txtres2.value = 'Fr. ' + Math.round(num4) + '.-';
} 
</script>```

Comment: hm no, still the same: after pressing the button twice

Answer (score 0):

```js
const form = document.forms['formcalc'];
const button = form.querySelector('input[type=button]');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  const inputNumberOneValue = form.elements['txtres'].value;
  const inputNumberTwoValue = form.elements['txtres2'].value;
  const result = document.querySelector('#lead');

  result.innerText = ` Number 1 is: ${inputNumberOneValue}. Number 2 is: ${inputNumberTwoValue}`;
})
```